# Can a Linux server that authenticates against an Active Directory accept public/private keys for passwordless login?

Tags: scripting, authentication, key-authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I have a Linux server that authenticates users against an Active Directory. Now interactive logins require username and password and automatic login requires a keytab (Kerberos) for passwordless authentication.

However, I have read in [NIST IR 7966](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2015/NIST.IR.7966.pdf) that keytab authentication is not as secure as public/private key pair authentication because in this case you can restrict the access to the execution of a command and you have more control over what systems can the user authenticate.

**So, I would like to use public/private key pair and continue authenticating against an Active Directory from a Linux server. Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can require both kerberos and public key authentication with  `AuthenticationMethods` sshd option.

[man 5 sshd_config](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config):

> **AuthenticationMethods**
>
> Specifies the authentication methods that must be
>   successfully completed for a user to be granted
>   access.  This option must be followed by one or
>   more comma-separated lists of authentication
>   method names.  Successful authentication requires
>   completion of every method in at least one of
>   these lists.
>   [...]
>   This option will yield a fatal error if enabled if protocol 1 is also enabled. Note that each authentication method listed should also be explicitly enabled in the configuration.

So, you need to write in your sshd_config something like this:

```
Protocol 2
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes 

AuthenticationMethods gssapi-with-mic, publickey
```

Comment: You may also use "Match User" sections to force pubkey only for specific users if you want to ensure that password/krb authentication can not be used.